# Guide: How to make node js application which is http work on a https front end

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, https, ssl-certificate

I could not find a single comprehensive guide on this issue so I thought I'd create a easy guide for those who find themselves with a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

***what I used:***

1. vps with cpanel for front end.
2. amazon ec2 linux for back end node js app
3. follow this guide to install node js on ec2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHAQ3TzUTro

problem: node js app does not output anything on a https front end.

***solution:*** install nginx server and use that to convert your http backend to a https subdomain so it can be displayed by the https front end.

***example:***
Point your subdomain to the ip of your ec2 instance ex: api.mywebsite.com => 11.22.33.44

in this example a nodeJS app  hosted on a ec2 instance on port 8080 with IP http://11.22.33.44:8080

currently the clock doesn't display anything on https://mywebsite.com. but it should work on http://mywebsite.com

get autossl certificates from cpanel for https://mywebsite.com. and https://api.mywebsite.com.

copy and paste the certificate block of text into a notepad

copy and paste the private key block of text into a notepad

Follow this guide to install nginx and redirect your node js app at   http://11.22.33.44:8080 TO http://11.22.33.44
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_EBARqreeao

now connect to your ec2 instance with ssh.

```
sudo mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl

sudo chmod 700 /etc/nginx/ssl
```

this creates a folder to put your server.crt and server.key in.

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt
```

copy your autossl certificate of api.mywebsite.com and save

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key
```

copy your autossl private key of api.mywebsite.com and save

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

now go back to your configuration file from the previous video and change the locations of your ssl certificate and ssl key

[image]

the bottom of your .conf file should look like this.

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

now reload your server and https://api.mywebsite.com should load whatever is on http://11.22.33.44:8080 with a "connection is secure" tag. and your https front end https://mywebsite.com should display what is on https://api.mywebsite.com